# Facebook Application is very slow

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have developed facebook application using facebook API, i have include the facebook api on top of the page and it is loading for all the pages because i am using the api in all the pages , i don't know whether this was the problem my application taking time to laod,

can any one advice me how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Before we can possible start to _solve_ your problem, you should first __describe__ in a manner that makes it comprehensible – explain some more what exactly you’re doing, show some code, …

Comment: No offense, but this might be the vague-est question I've ever seen. You're gonna have to give us more than that. What does your app *do*? Where are you seeing the slowness?

Answer (score 4):

Since your tag says Javascript, I'm assuming you're using the Javascript SDK around the Graph API.  Please see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/  as this talks about how not having correctly specified the channel url html file will make the JS SDK run very slowly.

Here's the important part of it:

> **Channel File**
>
> The channel file addresses some issues with cross domain communication
>   in certain browsers. The contents of the channel.html file can be just
>   a single line:
>
> ```
>   <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
> ```
>
> It is important for the channel file to be cached for as long as
>   possible. When serving this file, you must send valid Expires headers
>   with a long expiration period. This will ensure the channel file is
>   cached by the browser which is important for a smooth user experience.
>   Without proper caching, cross domain communication will become very
>   slow and users will suffer a severely degraded experience. A simple
>   way to do this in PHP is:
>
> ```
>  <?php
>  $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
>  header("Pragma: public");
>  header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
>  header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
>  ?>
>  <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
> ```
>
> The channelUrl parameter is optional, but recommended. Providing a
>   channel file can help address three specific known issues. First,
>   pages that include code to communicate across frames may cause Social
>   Plugins to show up as blank without a channelUrl. Second, if no
>   channelUrl is provided and a page includes auto-playing audio or
>   video, the user may hear two streams of audio because the page has
>   been loaded a second time in the background for cross domain
>   communication. Third, a channel file will prevent inclusion of extra
>   hits in your server-side logs. If you do not specify a channelUrl, you
>   can remove page views containing fb_xd_bust or fb_xd_fragment
>   parameters from your logs to ensure proper counts.
>
> The channelUrl must be a fully qualified URL matching the page on
>   which you include the SDK. In other words, the channel file domain
>   must include www if your site is served using www, and if you modify
>   document.domain on your page you must make the same document.domain
>   change in the channel.html file as well. The protocols must also
>   match. If your page is served over https, your channelUrl must also be
>   https. Remember to use the matching protocol for the script src as
>   well. The sample code above uses protocol-relative URLs which should
>   handle most https cases properly.